# Seleccionar un elemento de una lista ul de html

Tags: html5

Buenas amigos, soy nuevo en esto y quisera ver si me pueden ayudar, estoy haciendo un proyecto donde debo seleccionar de una lista UL un elemento y dependiendo del elemento seleccionado ejecutar unas acciones.

```
<ul>
  <li>Accion 1</li>
  <li>Accion 2</li>
  <li>Accion 3</li>
</ul>
```

Elemento seleccionado

Si selecciono la accion 1
.....

Si selecciono la accion 2
....

Si selecciono la accion 3
.....

gracias por la ayuda que me puedan dar

Comment: explicame mas a detalles de tu problema, que tipo de acciones quieres ejecutar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer eso con [jQuery](http://jquery.com), que te da grandes posibilidades de cambiar contenidos de tu página de forma interactiva sin tener que refrescarla.

En el ejemplo jQuery escucha los click de cada elemento `li` dentro de los `ul` de la clase `menu` y a través de `this` (elemento actual) obtiene el `id` de ese elemento y lo muestra en un `div` que tiene como id `resultado`.

jQuery te da posibilidades enormes para hacer eso y más.

Código de ejemplo:

```js
$(function(){ 
   $('ul.menu li').click(function(e) 
   { 
       $( "#resultado" ).text( "Seleccionaste: "+this.id);
       /* Aquí si quieres lanzar más acciones de acuerdo al li
           seleccionado puedes implementar un if then else
           u otra estructura de condicionales */
   });
});
```

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">
    <li id="Accion 1"><a href="#" >Acción 1</a></li>    
    <li id="Accion 2"><a href="#" >Acción 2</a></li>    
    <li id="Accion 3"><a href="#" >Acción 3</a></li>    
</ul>
<hr />
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

También lo puedes hacer escribiendo gestores de eventos para el onclick de cada elemento de la lista:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Acciones</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <style type="text/css">
          li:hover {
              background-color:  blue;
              color:  azure;
          }
        </style> 

        <script type="text/javascript">
          function accion1(){
            alert("Acción 1 pulsada");
          }
          function accion2(){
            alert("Acción 2 pulsada");
          }
          function accion3(){
            alert("Acción 3 pulsada");
          }

        </script>  
    </head>
    <body>
      <ul>
        <li onclick="accion1()">Acción 1 </li>
        <li onclick="accion2()">Acción 2 </li>
        <li onclick="accion3()">Acción 3 </li>        
      </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```